# "Sometime" or "Sometimes"

Tags: commas, error

> Sometime it is difficult to live a honest life.

Should *sometime* be changed to *sometimes* and should there be a comma after it?

Answer (score 3):

**1. Yes, it should be *sometimes* instead of *sometime*, as you are referring to multiple times.**

**2. There can be a comma there, depending on how you wish your sentence to sound.**

Also *a* should be changed to *an*, because *honest* begins with a vowel sound.

> Sometimes(,) it is difficult to live an honest life

*It is* is also generally changed to *it's*, but either one is grammatically correct.

Comment: I want to upvote this for your good and simple answer about sometimes, but why are you so prescriptive about the comma?

Comment: It is **sometimes** difficult to live an honest life. But: **Sometimes, it is difficult to live an honest life**.

Comment: @joidevivre Good point, I have edited my answer to reflect it. (I commented once before but it didn't show up for me, so if this is a duplicate, I apologize.)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes is an adverb, and **refers to frequency** (it works like: never and, always) These adverbs often (but not always) are used with simple present.

Sometimes, grammar is difficult.
Grammar is sometimes difficult.

Sometime: a time, in the sense of **when one does something**, but not on a clock

**You should come and see me sometime**. Also, an **adverb**, which refers to an undefined point in time or unspecified.

Also, sometime is an **adjective**:

He was a sometime librarian. [from time to time he worked as a librarian]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should say **sometimes.**

There are at least two uses of the two-word expression *some time.* First, it can refer to a specific occasion that is certain in our minds but has not yet been determined: **Come and see me some time.** Second, according to the normal usage of the word **some** (as a [partitive](https://www.thoughtco.com/partitive-in-grammar-1691587)) it can refer to an indefinite quantity of time, as in: **Give me some time to finish this.**

About the comma, there is a difference of opinion. Some people say that when a sentence begins with **sometimes** it needs a comma, because what follows is a dependent clause. But either way, people will understand you.

Comment: There is no such word as **sometime**? What's this, then, https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sometime ?

Comment: Good grief, that was a bad one. Thanks, @MichaelRybkin.

Comment: Much better, but what do you have against the one-word "sometime," which can be either an adverb or an adjective? _I don't need a sometime partner. I want a divorce._

Answer (score 0):

Sometime

1 archaic: in the past, formerly: James Smith, sometime professor of English at Northern College.

2 archaic: occasional: a sometime contributor to this newspaper. (Chiefly US usage, say some sources)

3 at some time in the future: I'll do it sometime

4 at some not specified or definitely known point of time: sometime last night

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sometime

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sometime